# How should I fix this asynchronicity problem in my "Josephus Problem" code?

Tags: javascript

### Background

I'm new to JavaScript and am solving various formulations of the Josephus Problem to better understand the syntax. Using a circularLinkedList implementation*, I've solved the classic formulation: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Josephus_problem)||[Numberphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCsD3ZGzMgE). I've also solved the problem for any fixed number of fighters and a fixed number of skips between eliminations (e.g., if skipping two fighters between eliminations, 1 eliminates 4, 5 eliminates 8, etc). I am now trying to solve the problem **given any function that indicates the number of skips at a given moment**.

### Problem

I can't access the return value of my skip function. I understand from [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function?noredirect=1&lq=1) that my issue involves asynchronicity, but am having trouble isolating takeaways from the long responses involving AJAX and jQuery, which I'm unfamiliar with. Could I get an ELI5 solution? I apologize for my lack of understanding.

### Code

```
    function winnerStepFunc(num, func) {
        let cll = new circularLinkedList(); //Initializing list with participants
        for (let a = 0; a < num; a++) {
            cll.append(a);
        }
        function next(funcSteps) { //Generating string indicating #steps from function's output 
            let toEvaluate = "start";
            for (let i = 0; i < funcSteps; i++) {
                toEvaluate += ".next"
            }
            return toEvaluate; 
        }
        let start = cll.getHead(); //Selecting first eliminator 
        while (cll.size() > 1) {
            let toCheck = func();                                     // PROBLEM LINE 
            console.log("toCheck = " + toCheck);                      //toCheck = undefined
            let str = next(toCheck);
            while (eval(str) !== start  && cll.size() > 1) { //
                let locCurrent = cll.indexOf(start.element);
                start = eval(str).next;
                cll.removeAt(((locCurrent + toCheck)% cll.size()));
            }
            cll.delete(eval(str).next.element);
            start = start.next;
        }
        console.log(start.element + 1);
    }
    
    function callFunction(name, args) {                // builds function string to be evaluated
        let result = name + "(";
        for (let i = 0; i < args.length -1; i++) {
            result += args[i] + ", ";
        }
        result += args[args.length-1] + ")";
        return result;
    }
    function callFunction(name) {
        let result = `${name}()`;
        return result;
    }
    function addOne() {                             //<--The first basic example I'm trying:
        return ++globalTimes;                       //Make the step increase by one for each elimination
    }
    var globalTimes = 0;
    winnerStepFunc(12, function(){eval(callFunction("addOne"))});
```

*[CLL Implementation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiI6OqywMfuAhWVJTQIHfQrC7AQFjABegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearnersbucket.com%2Ftutorials%2Fdata-structures%2Fcircular-linked-list-implementation-in-javascript%2F&usg=AOvVaw3JQlOorgzvGr3Ezvqk6N6k)

Comment: Why not call it like `winnerStepFunc(12, function(){ return addOne()});`? Do you need the eval? Also dont forget to return in the function passed to `winnerStepFunc`.

Comment: Hi @PaulRooney. I agree that I don't need the function that itself creates the string for another function; I'm not sure why I thought that would add functionality. Your suggested change fixed the code! The only other thing I needed was to change the inner while loop to an if loop. Thank you!

Comment: I made it an answer. Let me know if it has any issues.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return in your function. I would remove all the eval stuff and just call the function directly.

```
winnerStepFunc(12, addOne);
```